# getting difference between two SYSTEMTIME variable

Tags: winapi, systemtime

For Example my code is as follows.

```
void main()

{

       SYSTEMTIME LocalTime_Start = { 0 };

        GetLocalTime( &LocalTime_Start );

        SYSTEMTIME LocalTime_End = { 0 };
        // Some program Statements

         GetLocalTime( &LocalTime_End );

         // Now i want difference of two i.e.
         // can i do as following
         SYSTEMTIME localTime_diff = LocalTime_End - LocalTime_Start;
         // guys please let me know how to achieve that asap...thanks a lot in advance
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert both SYSTEMTIME structures to FILETIME using

```
FILTETIME ft;
::SystemTimeToFileTime(&sysTime, &ft);
```

Convert FILETIME to ULONGLONG using:

```
ULARGE_INTEGER uli;
uli.LowPart = ft.dwLowDateTime ;
uli.HighPart= ft.dwHighDateTime;
ULONGLONG uft= uli.QuadPart;
```

Subtract ULONGLONGs to get time difference in HectoNanoSec

Comment: Not applicable in this case but SystemTimeToFileTime will fail if the input SYSTEMTIME represents ZERO time (that is all its members are 0).